# Running Visual Studio web project shows 'Object not found' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to run a Visual Studio ASP.NET project, however I get the following error in the web browser window which appears on startup:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

The URL it is trying to load is:

```
 https://localhost/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

Strangely enough, in Project Properties > Web > Project URL, it is set to `http://localhost:8080`. Shouldn't the URL in the web browser also show this URL?

Comment: What does Project Properties > Web > Start URL say?

Comment: Start URL is blank. The Start Action is set to 'Current Page'

Comment: check your RouteCofig.cs

Comment: In that case I would say you have an redirect.

Comment: I'm assuming that the "Current Page" has a route with an Authorize attribute, and you're not logged in, so it's redirecting you to login and that doesn't exist? You'll have to post some more code for help, I think.

Comment: @EliAlgranti Where can I edit this redirect?

Comment: @john Thanks for the help so far. The issue is more about the fact that the project is running at https://localhost, when the project URL is set to http://localhost:8080